# Rails active admin free search on select element

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I am using [active admin gem](http://activeadmin.info/).

i have questions table that have relationship with user_id, when i want to add new questions the select element is showing with tons of users, there is a way to make this select element along with search input for user name?

```
ActiveAdmin.register Question do

  permit_params :difficulty, :title, :user

  form do |f|
    actions

    inputs 'Question Details' do
      input :user, :as => :select, :collection => User.all

      input :difficulty, as: :select, collection: [1,2,3,4]
      input :title

    end

    actions
  end


end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a javascript plugin, I'd thoroughly recommend chosen
It will dynamically turn a regular form select into a searchable select with a simple Javascript call.

You can checkout some demos here:
http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/

You can integrate it into activeadmin by adding the [chosen-rails](https://github.com/tsechingho/chosen-rails) gem to your Gemfile

```
gem 'chosen-rails'
```

Then add the javascript to your `app/assets/javascripts/active_admin.js.coffee`

```
#= require chosen-jquery
```

Add the css to your `app/assets/stylesheets/active_admin.scss`

```
@import "chosen"
```

You can add it to all your select inputs by simply adding the following to `app/assets/javascripts/active_admin.js.coffee`

```
$ -> 
  $("#active_admin_content select").chosen()
```

You could also limit it to certain select inputs by adding a class to active admin inputs and only targeting those selects with a specific class like `chosen-select`